# What is the simplist way to fit dynamic text to the size of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

So I have a slightly weird problem. I'm working on an app that need a basic output view with some dynamic text. For example the text could be `Next goal: <Goal>` and that  could be a string of any length. Is there a way to make the text scale with the size of the screen to maxamize readability but also guarantee that the text won't go off the edge?

I'm using svelte-kit as my frontend framework. I tried [svelte-textfit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-textfit) but it either made the text tiny or didn't auto resize. Maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Viewports can be any size and as your text can be of any length you can’t guarantee it will fit and still be readable. Are there some limits in font size you can place?

Comment: @AHaworth no fontsize limits so I was thinking something dynamic although I couldn't get it to work

Comment: You can keep filling the element with different font sizes until the text fits but you may end up with something unreadable if you don’t set a minimum size.